# Proof of Pettis' theorem about strong and weak measurability.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, bochner-spaces

I am studying Bochner integral, reading K.Yosida "Functional Analysis 6th edition."
However, I cannot understand the proof of Pettis' theorem, which is in p.131-132.
From my perspective, this proof assumes the following proposition in its last sentence, but I cannot show it.

#### Proposition.

Let $(S,\mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $X$ be a Banach space.
And let $f_n:S \to X$ is strongly measurable and $f_n(s) \to f(s)$ in $X$ for $a.e.s \in S$.
Then, $f$ is strongly measurable.

Definition of *simple* and *strongly measurable* are as follows:

#### Definition.

Let $(S,\mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $X$ be a Banach space.
$f:S \to X$ is called simple
if there exist $x_1, \dots, x_N \in X$ and $X_1, \dots , X_N \in \mathcal{F}$
such that $f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \chi_{X_n}(s) x_n$ for all $s \in S$.
$f: S \to X$ is called strongly measurable
if there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
such that $f_n(s) \to f(s)$ in $X$ for $a.e. s \in S$

Comment: I don't think your proposition is assumed on p 131. Where exactly is that proposition used?

Comment: Try a diagonalization argument?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm sorry. The proof last up to p.132. I think the proof uses this proposition in its last sentence, which is in p.132.

Comment: @user58955 I tried it, but it didn't work...

Comment: @fujiyamath Oh, since each $f_n$ is a limit of simple function, apart from a set $A_n$ of measure 0, the image of $f_n$ is separable; hence, let $A = \bigcup A_n$, which also has measure 0, we know that $f(X\setminus A)$ is separable. How about now?